# XQuartz refusing connections after a while

Tags: macos, x11, xquartz

When I open a new Terminal and ssh into a server, XQuartz runs fine.  But after a few minutes it stops accepting connections from that Terminal, with messages like

```
application-specific initialization failed: couldn't connect to display "localhost:14.0"
```

and if I want to use git gui or xemacs again I have to open a new Terminal.